# code first approach with dynamic model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can we implement the code first approach using dynamic model.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model1 context = new Model1();

    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var marksModel = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;

    string studentName = "Alice";
    marksModel.Add("rollNo", studentName);
    marksModel.Add("Name", studentName);
    marksModel.Add("Physics", 24);
    marksModel.Add("Chemistry", 45);
    marksModel.Add("Biology", 31);

    context.ExpandoObject.Add(expando);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In Context Class

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{

    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

   public  DbSet<ExpandoObject> ExpandoObject { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to do using dynamic model ?

Comment: and how is EF supposed to create a table using this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

At a glance, you appear to want to append random attributes to entities, and store those attributes as column values. So your solution is to find a database solution that lets you go schemaless, you add a bag of data to that database, and then end up in a hell trying to find out how to query something meaningful out of your data.

This is how people generally end up with both a document database and a depression.

Instead you need to read a thing or two about database normalization. You have a couple of relations between students and courses or exams, or whatever those numbers are meant to represent.

So model that:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
{
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public decimal Grade { get; set; }
}
```

And the need to use a "dynamic model" goes away.